# JQuery data() setting not persisting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a chrome extension, and in my "content.js" file I am attempting to create a div, then add data to it using JQuery.

Here's the relevant code in "content.js":

```js
var childrenDiv=document.createElement("div");
childrenDiv.id="childrenDiv";
document.body.appendChild(childrenDiv);
$("#childrenDiv").data("childwindows",[]);
$("#childrenDiv").data("childwindows");
console.log($("#childrenDiv").data("childwindows"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When the extension is enabled and I load the page, I get the expected output of "[]" in the console.

If I stay in the console, however, and try

```
$("#childrenDiv").data("childwindows");
```

again, it returns "undefined". Why is this? I would expect data bound to a DOM element to persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Content scripts work in an isolated environment from the page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#isolated_world). This means that while both the page and the content script can work with the DOM and any console log messages will be sent to the same console, they do not share functions, variables, etc.

So the jQuery you are using inside your console(the page's jQuery), is not the same jQuery being used by your content script. This means data stored through your extension's jQuery `data()` is not accessible by your page's jQuery hence why you get `undefined`

If you want to use the console in the environment your content script is running then go into your Dev Tools console tab and select your extension from the dropdown as seen below:

[image: Context Dropdown]

Comment: Got it, thanks. 

The goal here was to store a list of window objects on the page that can be accessed and modified by future click event scripts (just want to handle child windows previously opened). sessionStorage is a no-go since window objects can't be JSON-stringified (unless I refer to them by "name" which didn't seem like a clean/scalable solution). 

Any pointers in the right direction for the cleanest way of going about this? Was hoping to avoid server calls / cookies since I don't need persistence over refresh/future access.

Comment: @Borealis You can still store your data with the `data()` calls. Your data will be saved as long as the page doesn't reload. And your content script will still have access to it. You just tried viewing the data from the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var childrenDiv = document.createElement("div");
childrenDiv.id = "childrenDiv";
document.body.appendChild(childrenDiv);
$.data($("#childrenDiv")[0], 'childwindows', []);
console.log($.data($("#childrenDiv")[0], 'childwindows'));
```

Comment: Right, that works if I run it all in the original content.js file, but not if I run the above console.log command in the console after content.js has terminated (I tried it).